# setting up DB connections on the fly for models?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm creating a multi-tenant application and assigning a DB to each user and his/her sub-users. 
I first fetch the DB name / password / username for this user and then I need to make it the default for all DB operations to follow. 
 How to accomplish this in Laravel 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the connection method:

```
User::connection('master')->where('name', $name)->get();
```

And you can use the repository pattern to help you with this too:

```
 class PostRepository {

    private $connection = 'default-connection';

    public function setConnetion($connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function all()
    {
        return Post::on($this->connection)->all();
    }

    public function query()
    {
        return Post::on($this->connection);
    }

}
```

It will let you:

```
$post = new PostRepository;

$post->setConnection('new-connection');

return $post->query()->where('name', $name)->get();
```

or

```
return $post->all();
```

You can also create a BaseModel and do inside it:

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

    private $connection = 'default-connection';

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            $this->setConnection(Auth::user()->database_connection);
        }
    }

}

class Post extends BaseModel {

}
```

Comment: Is not there an easier way? instead of doing that on every model ? can I put something in the model constructor?

Comment: Also, I believe it is User::on('connection-name')->find(1) or I'm wrong?

Comment: You are limited only by your imagination. And, yes, you are right Naughty Coder. Just edited to provide a way to do it in all of your models.